# android google signin and facebook login button look completely different

Tags: android, google-plus, assets, android-facebook

The default Facebook LoginButton object and the Google SignIn button object have completely different appearances and they do not fit in my existing layout together. To my knowledge, these objects are not assets I can modify without changing the library itself (where I would assume these components are also open source)

How do people deal with this? I have seen apps that have sign-in options for both of those that use their own custom buttons, but in my implementation I am using those given objects that automatically call their respective libraries on click.

I can of course dive deeper, but I feel like I am reinventing the not-so-obvious wheel if I did that

```
 <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

This object is not so obviously a button, and I haven't yet inspected to see if it really is a button.

I need to use different assets for both the Google+ and Facebook Login button.

What I have

[image]

An android example I like (Duolingo app)

[image]

edit:
after some very simple layout adjustments, this is the result (in landscape mode, just to illuminate the problem)

[image]

these buttons are still very different and I need a different asset that will still access the correct methods. I sort of get how to do it with Facebook, thanks to the examples, but Google sign in is pretty cryptic to me right now

Comment: have you tried setting the layout_width attribute to an actual width instead of wrap_content?

Comment: okay now I feel cognitively negligent, @PatrickEvans, maybe I can put it within a FrameLayout and set the buttons to match_parent

Comment: @PatrickEvans okay, so I got them to line up with `match_parent` parameters, but they still look completely different. The pipe | between the logo and the rest of the button are in different places, the facebook button looks horrible in landscape mode... I wonder how other people deal with this

Comment: You can create you own buttons (as long as they comply with the branding requirements), which is what Duolingo did. Nothing says the FB button must have those exact rounded corners.

Comment: I am try to implement the facebook login in my app. From ur question it shows that u have done with this.. I did many search... kindly can u help me in implementing the facebook... i have butoon when user login it shows logout button on the same activity which i dont want... kindly help me @MartínMarconcini

Comment: @pareshy Implementing Facebook Login on Android is relatively easier than before with the new Facebook 3.x SDK. I did it following these steps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ If you have troubles, compile the samples that come with the SDK that work and take it from there. It's really not too complicated (albeit a little bit lame compared to G+). If you have further questions, either search for specific problems or post a new question. Good luck!

Comment: http://karunadheera.com/index.php/archives/160 I followed guidelines from this same post. I made it as exactly as I wanted.

Comment: That website is not working anymore. Any chance you could share the actual solution with us?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To change the text on the Facebook button use:

```
fb:login_text="Put your login text here"
fb:logout_text="Put your logout text here"
```

You will also need to add this to the button:

```
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

like so:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        fb:login_text="Sign in with Facebook"
        />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This :
Add this method to your activity:

```
protected void setGooglePlusButtonText(SignInButton signInButton, String buttonText) {
        for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);

            if (v instanceof TextView) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                tv.setTextSize(15);
                tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
                tv.setText(buttonText);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Add following line in **onCreateMethod** 
(where you have init the id's) :

```
setGooglePlusButtonText(btnSignIn, getString(R.string.common_signin_button_text_long));
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are not styled in exactly the same way - different curve on the corners and use of drop shadows.  So its not possible to make them look exactly the same.  The closest I could get was to make a vertical linear layout with a precise width of 215dip - and set the width of the buttons to be match_parent:

[image]

This used the following layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="215dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With the Google+ button, you can simply use your own asset -  `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` behaves the same as `android.widget.Button` and you register an onClick handler in the normal way.  Just be sure to follow Google's branding guidelines when you create your asset:

https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines

Note however that Google+ button does provide translations which you will need to create yourself if you implement your own button in several languages.

Comment: I love how one button says Log in and the other Sign in ;)

Comment: Check this out how I customized them to look exact. http://karunadheera.com/index.php/archives/160

Comment: The link is dead, can you repost ?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest sdk, both the buttons looks similar. The code and results are mentioned below.

**Step 1: build.gradle**

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

**Step 2: myActivity.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

**Step 3: Result**
[image]
**Step 4: Updated build.gradle with latest gcm**

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

**Step 5: Result**

[image]

Comment: With the new SDKs it get disgusting, so they are making us break the "rules" of their brands...